# Bootstrap with Salesforce

Tags: visualforce, bootstrap

I am trying to create a simple page using Bootstrap within salesforce. I need this page to have the standard salesforce header and sidebar.  When I use the standard bootstrap library via a CDN and the page is affecting all the CSS styling for my standard salesforce headers and side bars. Any help on how to prevent this ?

Comment: I'm assuming you want to keep the headers and side bars?

Comment: Yes I want to keep the header and sidebar

Comment: Unsure if this should be a comment or an answer so I will air on the side of caution......In order to use the standard sidebar and headers of SF with a bootstrapped page, you need to namespace the Bootstrap css files.  Check out this post on how you can accomplish this.  [http://bracketlabs.com/blog/2014/1/20/bracket-labs-dreamforce-roundup-visualforce-and-bootstrap]

Comment: There are also some existing libraries out there you can leverage as well.  Visualstrap is one i have played with in the past [http://blogforce9dev-developer-edition.ap1.force.com/ProjectDetail?id=a0290000009MI61]

Comment: The namespacing is probably the way to go, but wouldn't another option be to use VF components? Create a VF Component with the content you want, styled with Bootstrap, then reference the component in a VF page that uses header and sidebar. I've never tried that, but hypothetically, I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: I think that is what I was looking for. Thanks. The link is dead though. I was able to search for the post from their blog.

Comment: oops. yeah sorry.  here is the link.  http://bracketlabs.com/blog/2014/1/20/bracket-labs-dreamforce-roundup-visualforce-and-bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add namespace your bootstrap css file to avoid it. Both Less and Saas supports namespacing css files.

Comment: Can you provide an example that illustrates how the namespace would be added in the Visualforce page? Or a link to an example?